# How to redirect log statements of 3rd party api to installer log file?

Tags: install4j

Is it possible to redirect log statements created by 3rd-party-api to the installation log file? Let's say I have integrated a library which logs the statements to the commons-logging api and now I need to get these statetments to the installation file. How could I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The install4j slf4j bridge by sonatype will help you to do this:

http://sonatype.github.io/install4j-support/install4j-slf4j

Comment: When I use the install4j-slf4j-bridge api I get the following error in the logfile: [ERROR] MyCustomInstallationAction [ID 366]: Missing: install4jlogger.properties. Do you know why?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not familiar with that component, I just know that is exists. You can try to open an issue on the Github repository

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Ingo's hint I got all the 3rd-party commons-logging log statements into the logfile of install4j. How I have done this? I added the following artifacts to my installer project:

```
org.sonatype.install4j:install4j-slf4j:1.1.1
org.slf4j.jcl-over-slf4j.1.7.21
```

That's it. Sometimes things are too easy to see the solution. Thank you, Ingo.